# Including both Accessible and Standard Blockly

Tags: blockly, google-blockly

I've been looking over the Accessible Blockly documentation, but I've been having some trouble figuring out exactly how I would do this.

We have a React-based app which uses various Blockly workspaces (with a variety of custom blocks and fields). I'd love to be able to set it up such that we could toggle between the standard Blockly workspace and an Accessible Blockly setup in order to give options for keyboard-only users, but the documentation doesn't really seem to consider this sort of case - it seems more to be controlled by the combination of files you include, and dynamically loading/unloading those files could be... tricky. Has anyone encountered or been able to configure a use case like this?

Comment: Which features of accessible Blockly are you interested in having?  Do you want the full accessible Blockly, or just specific keyboard shortcuts?  Loading both simultaneously isn't a use case we considered, but there may be other workarounds to get what you need.

Comment: I was thinking a full keyboard control situation. We have an app with support for some fairly complex logic blocks and I'm concerned that the keyboard shortcuts just won't be enough for someone with limited dexterity like a primary keyboard user. I'd like to add a keyboard-based toggle that would allow a keyboard user to switch over to accessible if they need, but it's a React-based single-page-app, so changing out the Blockly packages in the header dynamically is not an easy task.

Comment: Interesting--I'll pass that on to the rest of the team to consider as we move forward with accessibility work.  

In future you may want to post on our forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/blockly

We answer questions there much more promptly, and you can discuss solutions with other developers using Blockly.